# padronizar a quantidade de caracteres php

Tags: php

Estou trazendo algumas informações de um arquivo texto, porém tem um campo chamado descrição onde tem de 0 até 300 caracteres. Gostaria de padronizar os resultados. Por ex.: Vamos supor que um dos campos tenha a seguinte frase:

> Ele foi nascido no Rio de Janeiro, mas viveu sua vida na bela cidade
>   de São Paulo.

E outra frase:

> Ele nasceu na encantadora Bahia

Observem que o primeiro campo tem mais caracteres do que o segundo, porém tem campos que parecem poemas do Fernando Pessoa rs rs rs. Então usei o substr(), mas não trouxe resultados como eu deveria, pois como os campos trazem textos de diferentes tamanhos, gostaria de padroniza-los, ou seja, se uma frase conter 500 palavras e a outra trouxer 100 palavras, gostaria que todas fossem padronizadas para o mesmo espaço que uma frase de 200 palavras contém...

Comment: Interessante essa questão. Mas seguinte, qual metodologia será usada para escolher cada palavra a ser removida?

Comment: Olá Eduardo. Estou querendo padronizar, pois o arquivo texto será enviado para uma base de dados de um sistema do qual trabalha com posições na tabela. Faço o upload de um arquivo csv e consigo ajustar pelo sistema que fiz as primeiras posições, mas a última após da descrição do produto, tenho que ajustar manualmente. Se eu conseguisse padronizar na hora de gerar o arquivo texto esse campo, iria bater com a posição do banco de dados.

Comment: tentei usar substr($texto,0,100 + 100); mas também não funcionou

Comment: Armazene cada frase em uma string.
Depois, percorra todas as strings, pego o tamanho de cada uma, e calcule a média de tamanho.

Comment: mas elas já estão. Quando trago, estou separando em array[]. $dividir[0],$dividir[1],$dividir[2],...

Comment: Sua dúvida é como remover caracteres uma string php?

Comment: Remover eu consigo com o substr(). Preciso padronizar os tamanhos de cada frase. Se uma frase tiver 100 caracteres, ela contenha espaço suficiente para uma frase que contém 200 caracteres. Mesmo que coloque o &nbsp; para isso.

Comment: Crie um laço iterando suas strings (ou um array com suas strings), dentro do laço crie um for lendo o tamanho da string, se for maior que 200, você remove caracteres da string maior.

Comment: mas o problema é que eu teria que descobrir o tamanho de uma frase e com isso incluindo após a string, a quantidade de string que falta.

Comment: mas emendando na sua ideia, poderia fazer dessa forma: if(strlen($frase) < 150){ $novaFrase = $frase.... ; ?> aqui eu colocaria a quantidade de caracteres que faltam, ou seja, 50 caracteres. Mas tem como colocar string no final de uma string?

Comment: Se a frase for menor que 200 caracteres, você acrescenta espaço em branco.

Comment: Você pode concatenar.

Comment: vou tentar aqui e volto com os resultados.. rs rs

Comment: Conseguiu resolver?

Comment: Não sei se é o caso, mas por acaso a função str_pad http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.str-pad.php não ajudaria para isso

Comment: Conseguiu resolver a situação?

Comment: Olá Eduardo. Desculpe a demora, pois a semana passada foi corrida. A função do Marcelo Diniz me ajudou, porém vou deixar em aberto caso apareça outra solução.